# Which compiler is correct with respect to template method specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have not kept up with the intricacies of templates so just know enough to be dangerous. However, I ran to a problem (reported by one of our testers) where code compiled properly on Xcode (Clang) and Visual Studio 2019 but the behavior was different and I'm wondering which one was "correct"

Consider the following simple class:

```
template <class T>
class foo
{
   void set(int index, T value);
};
```

That default templated **set** method worked fine for most values of type **T** but I needed to specialize the behavior for a particular type, call it String.

So in the associated CPP file, I added the following:

```
template <>
void foo<String>::set(int index,  String value)
{
   // code here
};
```

Under Xcode, this worked perfectly fine. A call to **set** with a second parameter of **String** correctly invoked that specialized template.

However, the exact same code, compiled with Visual Studio failed, behaved differently. That same call with the **String** parameter just invoked the original **set** rather than than the specialized version.

I'm assuming that under Xcode, the compiler properly created a call with a signature that matched the specialized version that was available in the CPP file and hence was linked properly.

So my questions are:

1. Why did this work in Xcode but not in Visual Studio
2. Which compiler behaved correctly and should the issue be considered a bug in the other compiler?

Incidentally, I did try creating an explicit signature in the header file:

```
template<>
void foo<String>::set(int index, String value );
```

and Xcode didn't complain about it and everything still worked.  However, Visual Studio, while not complaining about that header signature, did complain at link time that it couldn't find a matching implementation and so:

3. Why did that not work?

While I did find a way to do it that worked for both compilers (essentially putting inline versions in the header file, I would really like to understand why this problem happened.

I thank people in advance.

Edit: bllow is a real example I just put together. This compiles and runs perfectly fine under Xcode (in particular, the string specialization is correctly called for variable g) but fails to link in Visual Studio 2019 with the following error

(
public: void __cdecl Foo<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > >::print(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator >)" (?print@?$Foo@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QEAAXHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main) referenced in function main
)

```
    Classes.h
    ---------
    #pragma once

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    template <class T>
    class Foo
    {
       public:
          void print(int index, T value)
             {
                std::cout << "Using implicit template\n";
             }
    };




    Classes.cpp
    -----------

    #include "Classes.h"


    template<>
    void Foo<std::string>::print(int i, std::string xyz)
    {
       std::cout << "Using explicit String template\n";
    }



    Main.cpp
    --------

    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    #include "Sub/Classes.h"

    //==============================================================================
    int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {

        Foo<double> f;
        
        f.print(1, 2.0);
        
        Foo<std::string> g;
        
        g.print(1, "abc");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `T value` and `String value`?

Comment: Please show real code that demonstrates your compilation failure, that can be cut/pasted ***exactly as shown*** and then it can be tried to compile with various compilers. The shown code is obviously not the real code, and it cannot be determined which compiler produces correct results, without actual code that exhibits diverging behavior from different compilers.

Comment: Without knowing how the code that calls `foo<String>::set()` sets things up  (e.g. does it have visibility of the definitions of both `foo` and `String`) it's impossible to say.   Reading up on providing a [mcve].

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps  Yes, sorry. As it happens, the code is actually part of a compiler for a special purpose language in which variable declarations are more like Pascal than C and sometimes I mix them up. I've edited the question to correct that error and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
I have created a tiny example and edited my original post to include the three files needed to demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: The error message references a class method, `Foo::show` that's nowhere to be found in the example, so this is not the real code either. But that's immaterial. The shown code violates the ODR, and such is ill-formed. Both compilers are correct. The shown code is ill-formed. You cannot specialize a class method like that. C++ templates don't work this way. You must specialize the class, not the class method.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry  - I renamed the methods from 'show' to 'print' when I posted them just to make it clearer what they were doing but forgot to update the error message, which now correctly shows "print"

I don't know what ODR is nor do I understand why you say both compilers are correct given that the XCode version runs and prints the correct message (the one defined in the specialized template).  

The code compiles, links and runs under Xcode, correctly displaying the specialized message when called from g

The code compiles but does not link under Visual Studio.

Comment: @David Short answer: move the contents of `Classes.cpp` to `Classes.h`. Long answer: Main.cpp cannot "see" the specialization you have done in Classes.cpp so it instantiates using the default template in Classes.h. As a result, Classes.cpp and Main.cpp have conflicting definitions of `Foo<std::string>::print`; that's what is meant by ODR violation.

Comment: @jcai Sorry but that's not the issue....I know how to deal with the issue to make it work on Visual Studio. The point is that what I wrote works perfectly in Xcode.  I can hypothesize why, as well (compiler generates the appropriate mangled name for the call, and the linker finds a matching implementation with the same mangled name so it works. There is no need to declare a specialized definition since the template class method will match both just fine. My question is WHY does this work fine in Xcode and is it a bug in Xcode or should the fact that it doesn't work in VC be a bug?

Comment: @David It "works" because it's undefined behavior. ODR violation means the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: The thing is, I find that XCode's approach is actually better. (I hate that one can't have formatted stuff in these comments). Consider, if you have template <class T>class Foo{ void set(T value); } then set(1), set (1.0), set ("xyz"), set(someValueOfSomeClass) are all legitimate calls (types all match the template) and a call can be generated, resulting in a mangled C++ function name. The linker is able to match the specialized implementation 'cos the mangled names are the same.  So there doesn't seem to be any need to require a specialized signature. Why is that not better?

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward declare the full specialization in the `.h` file to tell other translation units not to instantiate the general template.

```cxx
template <typename T> struct foo {
  void set(int, T);
};

template <>
void foo<String>::set(int, String);
```

If you don't do this, you're violating the **One Definition Rule**. This happens because, when compiling *other* .cpp files, the compiler doesn't know that a full specialization exists, and instantiates the general template.

Say in `bar.cpp` you write `foo<String>().set(1, {});`. The compiler constructs that function from the definition of the general template and emits it in the `.o` or `.obj` file. At link time, the linker sees multiple versions of `foo<String>::set`. It assumes they are equivalent and picks one at random. You can't know in general which it will pick. What's worse is that some calls to `set` could have been inlined, and the version called there could be different from the one the linker picked. This is why ODR violations are so dangerous.

Putting the forward declaration `template <> void foo<String>::set(int, String);` in the header tells **all** translation units "don't automatically instantiate this template, I promise to put this definition in some .cpp file." Now `bar.cpp` doesn't instantiate the template. It calls `foo<String>::set` as it would any other forward-declared function. `foo.cpp` provides the definition for that full specialization, and it is used everywhere.